# Driving a boat: Pull back or forward to go faster?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-iv

What is the way to drive fastest a boat?

I'm stuck in a mission where I have to follow an helicopter using a boat and never reach it.

I've tried both ways but I'm not sure if there is a trick or technique to drive faster a boat.

Comment: I never had an issue keeping up to the objectives in a boat on the PC version. During the entire time, I wasn't giving any input for a 'forward' or 'backward' lean. I'm surprised that there even is even input to 'lean' a boat, seeing as the throttle is the only real input you'd have to affect that in real life. (leaning yourself in a boat would have little to no impact in all but the smallest of boats) It's like being able to lean forward or backwards in a car.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can remember there is no special trick to go faster. In the speed boats you can pull back on the thumbstick to lift the front creating less drag or push forward making the nose go down a bit. I would pull back slightly to go faster but not too far/for too long becuse if you hit a wave the nose goes up too high and you lose speed.

Comment: Ok. It's better pull back sometimes, but no much. When I push forward, the boat goes a little slowly. Finally I reach the helicopter.